# Getting connect failed with SQLite3 and Classic ASP

Tags: sqlite, asp-classic

I am just testing the combination of SQLite database and asp classic to write a demo app. But, while doing so I am getting following error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

connect failed

/DBTest/test.asp, line 3
```

Here is the code:

```
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.mode =3
objConn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=test.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;"
```

Yes, I have installed driver for SQLite and I have create `test.db` database using SQLite, placed in same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ODBC Driver [ODBC](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/sqliteodbc.exe) and [ODBC x64](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/sqliteodbc_w64.exe)
and securty IIS permission true

I create sqlite db

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DATALAR` (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `isim`  TEXT,
    `data`  TEXT
);
INSERT INTO `DATALAR` VALUES (2,'hasan','deneme');
INSERT INTO `DATALAR` VALUES (3,'fehmi','dene');
COMMIT;
```

[image]

I use code for Classic Asp

```
<table>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>

    <%
    dbpath=Server.MapPath("sqliteveri.db")
    Baglanti = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver; Database="& dbpath &"; LongNames=0; Timeout=1000; NoTXN=0; SyncPragma=NORMAL; StepAPI=0;"
    Set bag = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    bag.ConnectionString= Baglanti
    bag.Open


    set recordSet = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
    SQL="Select * from DATALAR"
    recordSet.open SQL,Baglanti,1,3
    %>
    <% Do while not recordSet.eof %> 
   <tr><td><%=recordSet("isim")%></td><td><%=recordSet("data")%></td></tr>
    <%
    recordSet.MoveNext
    Loop
    %>  

    <%            


    recordSet.Close()
    bag.Close()

    %>

    </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of:

`objConn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=test.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;"`

using:

`objConn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & Server.mapPath( "test.db" ) & ";LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;"`

By doing this you make it clear for the driver where to find your database file.